# Bessel Function of the first kind

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions

Could you please help me understand how to prove

$$J_{(1/2)} (x) =  \sqrt{\frac2{\pi x}}\cdot \sin⁡ x$$

using,

$$J_p (x)  = \sum_{(n=0)}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n! \Gamma(n+p+1) )} \left( \frac x 2 \right)^{2n+p}$$

Thank you

Comment: What happened when you substituted $\frac12$ for $p$? Did you notice anything familiar?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site. (In particular, you can use commands like `\sin` to get the right font for operators, `\left` and `\right` before paired delimiters to let them adjust to the size of their content, and double dollar signs for displayed equations.)

Comment: @J.M. yes i did substitute $1/2$ for $p$ but i cant seem to simplify that to get $(2n+1)!$ in the denominator?

Comment: Are you familiar with how to manipulate the gamma function? In particular, are you familiar with the duplication formula?

Comment: @mythk http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

Comment: i did use this property of the gamma function $Γ(n+1/2+1)=  (1/2+n)(1/2+n-1)…………(1/2+1)Γ(1/2)$

where $Γ(1/2)=√π$

i hope this is correct :)

but i'm afraid i'm not familiar with the duplication formula

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki thank you

i did look into the prior to asking this, but i did not understand :)

Comment: @mythk I think JM may be referring to $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(-x)=\frac\pi{x\sin(\pi x)}$

Comment: @Simple, that's a reflection formula and not a duplication formula, which relates $\Gamma(2z)$ and $\Gamma(z+\frac12)$.

Comment: @J.M. Oops, my bad.  Well... have fun with that, this problem just seems tedious.

Comment: @Simple, it does involve a little algebra and sweat, but nothing that should take more than five minutes. :)

Comment: @J.M. That's easy for you to say.  Not that I've actually looked at the link Behrouz gave though.

Comment: @SimpleArt the link only has a general explanation about the Bessel Function.

Comment: @J.M. do i have to expand the Sigma?

or can i do it within the sigma?

Comment: @mythk, you shouldn't have to. All you need is familiarity with gamma function identities and an ability to recognize a familiar series when it shows up.

Comment: @J.M. you mean i should use the duplication formula? 
It is not taught in my module, is there another way?

Comment: Then how are you supposed to relate $\Gamma(n+\frac32)$ and $(2n+1)!$? :) But I notice you gave a relationship that uses the base case $\Gamma(\frac12)$; maybe you can consider how to relate that to a factorial expression.

Comment: $Γ(n+x)=  (x+n-1)(x+n-2)…………(x+1)xΓ(x)$ this is the relationship that i know. Is it useful?

Comment: it does sort of have a factorial expression :)

Comment: As I said, if you can figure out how to pull a factorial expression from that, then sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bessel Function of the first kind and order $p$ has series representation given by

$$J_p (x)  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n! \,\Gamma(n+p+1) } \left( \frac x 2 \right)^{2n+p} $$

For $p=1/2$, we find

$$\begin{align}
J_{1/2} (x)  &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n! \,\Gamma(n+3/2) } \left( \frac x 2 \right)^{2n+1/2} \\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac {1}{2x}}\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\,x^{2n+1}}{n! \,4^n\,\Gamma(n+3/2) } \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Applying recursively the functional relationship, $\Gamma(1+x)=x\Gamma(x)$, for the Gamma Function $\Gamma(n+3/2)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\Gamma(n+3/2)&=(n+1/2)(n-1/2)(n-3/2)\cdots (3/2)(1/2)\Gamma(1/2)\\\\
&=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{2^{n+1}}\sqrt \pi\\\\
&=\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^{2n+1}\,n!}\sqrt \pi \tag2
\end{align}$$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
J_{1/2}(x)&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2x}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\,x^{2n}}{n!\,4^n\,\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^{2n+1}\,n!}\sqrt \pi }\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\,x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\,\sin(x)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: this is very helpful. thank you

Comment: But could you please kindly further explain how applying the functional relationship recursively gives $(2n+1)!!/2^{(2n+1)}  √π$  ? I understand everything except that

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: To understand the result from the functional relationship, start with $n=1$.  Then, $\Gamma (3/2)=\frac12 \Gamma(1/2)=\frac12 \sqrt{\pi}$.  Then, for $n=2$, $\Gamma(5/2)=\frac32 \times \frac 12 \times \Gamma(1/2)$.  And so on.  Finally, for a general $n$, review the first line of Equation $(2)$ herein, and multiply through by $2^{n+1}$ to arrive at the second line.